# Return the correct timestamp

Tags: elixir

Right now I'm using `DateTime.utc_now()` and it returns this:

`~U[2019-07-27 19:44:24.834413Z]`

This is fine and dandy but I want a function that will return this:

`~U[2019-07-27 19:44:24]`

For the life of me, I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I wouldn't say the second one is more correct than the first, it's just less precise.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `~U[2019-07-27 19:44:24]` is malformed because of missing offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`DateTime.truncate/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#truncate/2) function.

```
iex(1)> dt = DateTime.utc_now()
~U[2019-07-28 01:56:57.902304Z]
iex(2)> DateTime.truncate(dt, :second)
~U[2019-07-28 01:56:57Z]
```